# salesforce standard mouse over functionlity in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, mousehover

How to  implement below salesforce standard functionality in lightning component

[image]

On account hover the popup should open and on mouse out the pop up should close.
Any standard methods are available? or fully customization required?

Please provide the pointers.

Comment: what have you tried ? Is there a specific code snippet where you are stuck ? This is almost like I have a requirement and please code for me . I suggest you try something out before posting a broad question like this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is called a "popover".

It can be implemented in a lightning component by including 
`<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>` in your component markup.

Here is a sample code from Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation), further details in chapter "Popovers"

**MyCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button name="popover" label="Show Popover" onclick="{!c.handleShowPopover}"/>
    <div class="mypopover" onmouseover="{!c.handleShowPopover}">Popover should display if you hover over here.</div>
</aura:component>
```

**MyCmpController.js**

```
({
    handleShowPopover : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
            body: "Popovers are positioned relative to a reference element",
            referenceSelector: ".mypopover",
            cssClass: "popoverclass, cMyCmp"
        }).then(function (overlay) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                //close the popover after 3 seconds
                overlay.close();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
})
```

**Note:** 
Any custom CSS class you add must be accompanied by the `cMyCmp` class, where `c` is your namespace and `MyCmp` is the name of the component that creates the popover.

You might need to adapt further the css for your needs.